# Make grey text black when surfing with Android

Tags: browser

Can I override the text color when browsing in android?
Firefox for android seems not to have that cool feature like on windows.

Comment: Can you give us a sample link that has gray text?

Comment: Or a screenshot would also do.

Comment: Which device are you using? Android Version? Rooted/Not rooted?